# Read stream from byte to byte

Tags: java, http

It is the mental challange of me that when i set range of bytes in **HttpRequest** or for any input stream, What is the interval that be selected to download ?! Closed interval [start, end] or left-closed, right-open [start, end) ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [HTTP specification, chapter 14: Header Field Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html):

> ### 14.35 Range
>
> #### 14.35.1 Byte Ranges
>
> The first-byte-pos value in a byte-range-spec gives the byte-offset of the first byte in a range. The last-byte-pos value gives the byte-offset of the last byte in the range; that is, the byte positions specified are inclusive. Byte offsets start at zero.

The examples there are very descriptive:

> Examples of byte-ranges-specifier values (assuming an entity-body of length `10000`):
>
> - The first 500 bytes (byte offsets 0-499, inclusive):  bytes=0-499
> - The second 500 bytes (byte offsets 500-999, inclusive): bytes=500-999
> - The final 500 bytes (byte offsets 9500-9999, inclusive): bytes=-500
> - Or bytes=9500-

So in short: the interval is closed (inclusive) and the number of bytes to download is `last - first + 1`.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is so complete :)